# How to perform a sum operation, excluding the first record

Tags: asp.net, mysql, linq

My table contains "hours" field. I have multiple records in my table.
I want to get the total of all "hours" fields except the first record.
How do I get the sum of all except first record?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Skip() method in Linq.

> var totalHours = dataContext.TimeZones.Skip(1).Sum(x=>x.Hours);

Comment: I am getting null If i implement like this,"hours" field is of type Tiny int